# MassTransit: dependency between messages

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Question regarding MassTransit with RabbitMQ.

I need to create a dependency between 2 messages.

1) Create new Contract
2) Update ContractOptions

The second message can only be executed after message 1 is completed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AMQP/RabbitMQ - Process messages sequentially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520676/amqp-rabbitmq-process-messages-sequentially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want a Saga - a long running workflow where things should happen in a certain order. http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/saga.html